# Как определить параметр z

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

Здоаствуйте, есть ссылка на яндекс карты https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=55.753088,37.587614

Перейдя на него яндекс карты автоматически выставляет `z` параметр.
Возможно ли как то в статик незная `z` чтобы он так же автоматически подобрал его как на яндекс карте?

И если можно объясните как он подбирает параметр `z`

Comment: А в чём проблема самостоятельно указывать масштаб? Карта по ссылке выставляет вам z=17, чтобы были видны дома. Сделайте так же! Хотите квартал охватить - уменьшите до 15, подъезды крупнее - 18-19. Карта подбирает масштаб, если у вас маршрут построен на ней или точек несколько, чтобы всё видно было. А с одной координатой зачем подбирать?

Comment: Координаты не одни я с Яндекс geocoder  беру ввод что вводит если находит присылаю ссылку в виде координат с адресом на Яндекс карты, ну я хочу прикрепить ему ссылку со Статик на местность с меткой ну с z проблема как его определить.

Comment: Что значит ссылку на статик? Static API обязан использоваться на публичном сайте, а не ссылкой! Это в пользовательском соглашении чётко прописано. Ссылки вы можете присылать только на саму карту по шаблону https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web-docpage/

Comment: Ну и опять же... Ссылка с адресом означает одновременно только одну точку на карте. И проставить ей зум вручную на желаемом уровне, как я выше писал, проблемы быть не должно. Если нет - приводите примеры

Comment: Человек может прислать координаты на Москву с адресом и домом а через минуту координаты на Чукотку и если вы как пишите установить зум в ручную а то есть для любым координат одинаковый то на Чукотку зум будет отдален. На яндекс карте тоже 1 точка ну зум ставит автоматически он

Comment: А если необходимо чтобы автоматический зум был, как Яндекс выставляет его по координатам?возможно как то это без ручного зума?

Comment: Да не нужен с одним объектом никакой атвозум! Ставьте всегда 17 и всё. Автозум нужен для группы объектов, которые могут быть с разных концов области или даже страны, чтобы их все было видно. Но вы же сами пишете, что такого не требуется - адрес один в каждой карте. Вот пусть и будет всегда 17 тогда.

Comment: Нет адреса всегда разные как и координаты вот в чем дело

Comment: Да какая разница, разные адреса или нет??? Главное, что на каждой новой карте один единственный адрес! Один адрес - один масштаб - 17! Пусть адреса меняются, а зум остаётся стандартным, что не так-то? Вот дом в Москве и Анадыре с одним зумом, всё норм: https://jsbin.com/gogiqaq/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Быть может нужны изображения для разных типов топонимов? Дома, города, области? Так не пойдёт. Делайте нормальный сайт и подключайте JS API Карту, которая решит вашу задачу просто и быстро.
Вызов веб-версии карт не выполняет определение масштаба сам по себе, когда используется поиск. Карта загружается, выполняется поиск, определяется масштаб объекта и по его границам выставляются границы карты методом, аналогичным тому, что в ответе. Выдавать вам бесплатно в Статик АПИ координаты с зумом по адресному запросу Яндексу нет никакого резона - серверное геокодирование - платный коммерческий сервис.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть Вы имеете в виду автоматическое масштабирование относительно определённой области?

Для этого можно использовать метод [setBounds](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#method_detail__setBounds).
Обновление масштаба при добавлении объектов на карту:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add("boundschange", () => {
  const bounds = myMap.geoObjects.getBounds();
  if (!bounds) return;
  myMap.setBounds(bounds);
}
```